# jQuery - flashMessage close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash-message

short question:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.flash-notice .close').click(function(e){
        $('.flash-notice').fadeOut(250);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
        $('.flash-notice').delay(3000,).fadeOut(1000);
```

When i click on the .close element of the Flash Notice, nothing happens. It just fades after 3 seconds. If i show it up again and click on the .close again, it works.

I guess it's a bit messed up with trying to close the box while it's already being closed.

How can i solve that?

Thanks!

Comment: `.delay(3000)`  _without that `,`_ BTW you are doing this on document ready --> `$('.flash-notice').delay(3000,).fadeOut(1000);` not on click ?

Comment: my goal is , to display a popup at page load and fade it out after 3 seconds or earlier if someone clicks the button

Answer (score 0):

```
        $('.flash-notice').delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
        $('.flash-notice .close a').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.flash-notice').stop().fadeOut(250);
        });
```

I forgot the stop()

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses a special effects queue to store animation and other effects. Any time you create a new effect, it's put at the end of the queue. In your case the effects are added to the queue in the following order:

1. `.delay(3000)`
2. `.fadeOut(1000)`
3. `.fadeOut(250)`

So the `.fadeOut(250)` method gets executed only after the previous two. The solution of your problem is to clear the effects queue before calling `.fadeOut(250)`. The following works:

```
$('.flash-notice .close').click(function(e){
    $('.flash-notice').stop().clearQueue().fadeOut(250);
    e.preventDefault();
});
$('.flash-notice').delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
```

`.stop()` terminates the currently running effect (`.delay(3000)`), `.clearQueue()` removes from the queue all effects that have not yet started.